# A difficult $\,Z$-transform

Tags: sequences-and-series, z-transform

I have to $\,Z$-transform the sequence

$$a(n)=\begin{cases} (n-2)^2\quad\text{ if }\,n\geq 2\\0\qquad\quad\text{ elsewhere }\end{cases}$$

I know that I have to use the time-shift rule, since $(n-2)^2$ is a shifted version of $n^2$  by two-steps.

So the shift-rule says $$y(n-k)\Theta(n-k)=z^{-k}Y(z)$$

Clearly, the first term is $z^{-2}$, and the relevant rule of transform for the other part is  $$a^n\rightarrow \frac{z}{z-a}$$
But I can't find the correct way to use it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}\displaystyle Z[a(n)]&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-2)^2z^{-n}\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{by letting }m=n-2}}{=}\,\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}m^2z^{-m-2}=\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\big[m(m+1)-m\big]z^{-m-2}=\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}m(m+1)z^{-m-2}-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}mz^{-m-2}=\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-m)(-m-1)z^{-m-2}+z^{-1}\!\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-m)z^{-m-1}=\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac d{dz}\left[(-m)z^{-m-1}\right]+z^{-1}\!\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac d{dz}\left(z^{-m}\right)=\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(z^{-m}\right)+z^{-1}\!\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac d{dz}\left(z^{-m}\right)=\\
&=\dfrac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}z^{-m}\!\right)+z^{-1}\frac d{dz}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}z^{-m}\!\right)=\\
&=\dfrac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(\!\frac1{1-z^{-1}}\!\right)+z^{-1}\frac d{dz}\left(\!\frac1{1-z^{-1}}\!\right)=\\
&=\dfrac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(\!\frac z{z-1}\!\right)+\frac1z\!\cdot\!\frac d{dz}\left(\!\frac z{z-1}\!\right)=\\
&=\dfrac d{dz}\left[\frac{-1}{(z-1)^2}\right]+\frac1z\!\cdot\!\frac{-1}{(z-1)^2} =\\
&=\frac2{(z-1)^3}-\frac1{z(z-1)^2}=\\
&=\frac{2z-(z-1)}{z(z-1)^3}=\\
&=\dfrac{z+1}{z(z-1)^3}\;.\end{align}$

Comment: Thanks, what a work!

Comment: @Luthier415Hz, you are welcome !

Comment: One question, how do you relate $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{-m}=\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}$$? Is it by geometric series?

Comment: Yes, it is the geometric series and $z^{-1}$ is its common ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The command of Mathematica 13.1

```
ZTransform[Piecewise[{{(n - 2)^2, n >= 2}, {0, True}}], n, z]
```

performs $$ \frac{z+1}{(z-1)^3 z}.$$

Comment: Thanks, but I need the hand-made method..

Comment: @Luthier415Hz, I have written an answer with a hand-made method. Please, look at it.